# Flutter Video_player fast forward 10 seconds using seekto not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the Flutter Video_Player plugin and am noticing some issues when I want to fast forward 10 seconds, so want to check if I am using the correct code.

What I am experiencing is that is takes a long time, to fast forward the play, if this happens then the tendency is to press fast forward again, and If I press it several times then i notice that the sound either is not in sync or can't be heard any longer.

Here is my code:

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        print('FORWARD 10 SECS');
                        await _controller.seekTo(Duration(
                            seconds:
                                _controller.value.position.inSeconds + 10));
                      },
```

I'd really appreciate it if I can get some help with this as the app I am working on is video focused so these controls do have to work correctly.

Thank you so much for any help with this. If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to await seekTo(), here is working code:
[image]

Check the complete code, hope it can help :)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(const VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const VideoPlayerApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
    );

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
    _controller.play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Video'),
      ),
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
            // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            );
          } else {
            // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
            // loading spinner.
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Duration currentPosition = _controller.value.position;
          Duration targetPosition = currentPosition + const Duration(seconds: 10);
          _controller.seekTo(targetPosition);
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this git [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61303). I think you don't need to add `await _controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds:_controller.value.position.inSeconds + 10)`. Instead add this `await _controller.seekTo((await _controller.position)! + Duration(seconds: 10));`. Not sure if `setState` is neccesory.